# Visual Studio Team Services on-premises build server

Tags: visual-studio-2013, build, proxy, azure-pipelines

Following these instructions (*[Deploy an agent on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/agents/windows?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)*), I have configured an VSTS build agent to run as a Windows service. The host server is configured to access the Internet through a corporate proxy server. I am able to browse to the target VSTS site through Internet Explorer from the server.

When I view "Agents for pool Default" I see my newly configured agent, but its status is "offline" and it has a red block rather than green. If I restart the agent service then I get the following error in the event log:

> The vsoAgent process failed to start successfully. It exited with code
>   3. Check the latest Agent log files in C:\VSTSBuild\agent_diag for more information. Waiting for 5 seconds before retrying.

However, on checking the _diag log files, there are no errors:

> 14:17:25.160120 Sending trace output to log files: 
>   C:\VSTSBuild\agent_diag 14:17:25.203125 VsoAgent.exe was run with the 
>   following command line: "C:\VSTSBuild\agent\agent\vsoagent.exe" 
>   /runningAsService  14:17:25.345132 SettingsFileHelper.Load - 
>   settings[AutoUpdate]=True 14:17:25.345132 SettingsFileHelper.Load - 
>   settings[RootFolder]=C:\VSTSBuild\agent 14:17:25.345132 
>   SettingsFileHelper.Load - 
>   settings[WorkFolder]=C:\VSTSBuild\agent_work 14:17:25.346130 
>   SettingsFileHelper.Load - 
>   settings[ServerUrl]=https://XXXXappdevteam.visualstudio.com 
>   14:17:25.346130 SettingsFileHelper.Load - 
>   settings[AgentName]=Agent-XXXX-NCC-BT001U 14:17:25.346130 
>   SettingsFileHelper.Load - settings[PoolId]=1 14:17:25.346130 
>   SettingsFileHelper.Load - settings[PoolName]=default 14:17:25.346130 
>   SettingsFileHelper.Load - settings[AgentId]=5 14:17:25.346130 
>   SettingsFileHelper.Load - settings[RunAsWindowsService]=True 
>   14:17:25.346130 SettingsFileHelper.Load - 
>   settings[WindowsServiceName]=vsoagent.XXXXappdevteam.Agent-XXXX-NCC-BT001U 
>   14:17:25.346130 SettingsFileHelper.Load - 
>   settings[WindowsServiceDisplayName]=VSO Agent 
>   (XXXXappdevteam.Agent-XXXX-NCC-BT001U) 14:17:25.381133 
>   BaseLogger.LogStatus(scope.JobId = 
>   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, scope.TimelineRecordId = 
>   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, record.Name = Agent) 
>   14:17:25.424136 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId = 
>   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, message = Authenticating to the 
>   server https://XXXXappdevteam.visualstudio.com) 14:17:25.449133 Exe 
>   location hash = ce01163e1787840dbffc06817bd93470

After a few minutes, the request times out and the following is added to the log:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending 
>   the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the 
>   remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection 
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond 
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because 
>   connected host has failed to respond 65.52.8.37:443

A colleague from the network team has run a trace against the proxy and confirmed that he can see requests coming from the agent's host server, but no response from visualstudio.com.

I have tried adding the following to the <Configuration> element of VsoAgentService.exe.config

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy>
  <proxy
    usesystemdefault="true"
    proxyaddress="proxy address here"
    bypassonlocal="true"
  />
</defaultProxy>
```

What should I check next or where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not running as a service, but from the cmd window - behind a proxy configured in Git globally.  I had connection issues with the VSTS recommended build agent (the one you download from within VSTS), but using the latest agent on GitHub, which authenticates with PAT, these problems go away:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar connection error as well despite being able to open the URL in the browser. My problem ended up being related to the proxy. If your proxy requires authentication, you will have to provide the credentials through environment variables if your service is not running as a network account with privileges to the proxy.

Try these steps:

1. Open CMD prompt
2. Set VSTS_HTTP_PROXY=http://yourproxy:80
3. Set VSTS_HTTP_PROXY_USERNAME=proxyuser
4. Set VSTS_HTTP_PROXY_PASSWORD=proxypassword
5. Restart the service.